# Javascript function Id

Tags: javascript

```
<label for="dessert">What is your favourite dessert?*</label>
<input type="text" id="dessert" onchange="checkForm()"><br>
<div id="dessertmsg">  </div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="subbutton" disabled>
```

I want to show the button. To show the button, I want my validation to be true which is :

```javascript
  function checkForm()

  {
  var dessert = document.getElementById("dessert").value;

  if(dessert == "cake"|| dessert == "cookie" || dessert == "icecream"){
```

When its true, i want the button to be enabled. I know i have to use disabled: False but how would i write the line of code for that? `document.getElementById(`what is the id for the disabled`)`??

Comment: how would i do it though? document.getElementById(subbutton, disabled: false);?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function checkForm() { 
    var button = document.getElementById("subbutton");
    var dessert = document.getElementById("dessert").value;
    if(dessert == "cake"|| dessert == "cookie" || dessert == "icecream") {
        button.disabled = undefined;
    }
    else {
        button.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/3NudE/ (with 3 nudes, woo!)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dessert == "cake"|| dessert == "cookie" || dessert == "icecream"){
    {document.getElementById("subbutton").disabled = false;}
```

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=147187

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkForm()
{
   var dessert = document.getElementById("dessert").value;
   document.getElementById("subbutton").disabled = (dessert == "cake"|| dessert == "cookie" || dessert == "icecream");
}
```